# Unwanted Extra Icons in Application

Tags: delphi, icons, delphi-2007

Using Delphi 2007. I am adding 2 extra icons to my app to use for some custom file associations. Using custom resource files and that is working correctly. However when looking at the resultant exe files I found some extra icons and I do not know where they coming from.

The result is my icons are becoming icons 5 and 6 instead of 1 and 2. Result is that when adding the custom file associations my DefaultIcon registry entry must use 5 and 6 instead of what I expected.

My concern is that since I don't understand where those icons are coming from I may cause myself problems in the future.

Any ideas where to look for them?

Comment: @Luke Delphi always includes some default icons.

Make a new VCL forms application with nothing in it, compile that and look at the icons in the resultant exe file. (use the source Luke) *sorry couldn't resist*

Comment: @Johan: Are you sure? I have never seen any [besides the application icon]...

Comment: @Johan: Tried a new vcl forms application and the only icon is the MAINICON.

Comment: @Yep you are right, you used to get extra icons with a MDI application though, but I checked in Delphi 2007 and only 1 icon comes out. I wonder when they changed that.

Comment: @Johan, They didn't.  Delphi only ever included a single icon by default.

Comment: @Bruce, OK I guess I'm mistaken

Answer (score 3):

Delphi adds a single icon to your exe (default or user specified).

If you are seeing more icons in your application, then they are either:

- Being added with a .rc file somewhere.
- They have been added directly to your project's .res file.

You can look at and edit the contents of your .res file using any resource editor.  Two good examples are applications from [Anders Melander](http://melander.dk/reseditor) and [Colin Wilson](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm).

UPDATE:

Since Luke didn't find another .rc file and his .res file is correct, here are a couple of other things I would try:

- Delphi 2007 supports pre and post build events.  See if there are any that might add resources.
- Look at the compiler output in the Messages window for any signs of an unexpected .res or .rc file.
- Search your source files for instances of ".res" or ".rc".

Comment: *a single icon which can have different "icons" based on size, i.e.: 256x256 has a teddy bear, 128x128 has a lion, 32x32 has a triangle, 24x24 has letter "D"

Comment: A single icon can have multiple images, but it is still essentially a single .ico.  Look at the MAINICON resource in a Delphi exe using a resource editor.

Comment: @Bruce: Used Resource editor from Anders Melander and discovered the following. The application res file only has one icon, the MAINICON which is what I expected. My custom resource has two icons which is what I expected. My exe has 7. Unaccounted icons are ReminderBell, vcl_ew, vcl_nesw, vlc_ns. Search source and cannot find any other .rc or .res references. No references to those icons either. Still stumped.

Comment: I'll add another suggestion or two.

Comment: Searching entire drive for .rc and .res files was not helpfull as I had 769 .rc files and 4k+ .res files. Searched source of third-party libraries (I use several) for the actual icon names and found LoadIcon refrerences to each of the four of icons.

Comment: @Luke, When you create a new Delphi application, does it have the expected number of icon resources?  If you add your .rc file, does it work the way you expect?

Comment: @Luke, in the app with ReminderBell, vcl_ew, etc., are you using any third-party components? They could be imported as resources by those products.

Comment: The VCL_* icons might come from the [IMouse unit](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/7/871794.html) or some other IntelliMouse/mouse wheel support stuff.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Bruce said, ResHacker is also a free tool to view the resources of your exe.

Also, Im not sure if this would work but could you store the icons you want in a resource dll, and extract/use them when you need to?